# pyQt window is doesn't update until I change window

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt, paintevent

I have a program that loads a file from the hard drive, with instructions to paint several squares of 50x50 pixels. I also have two `ComboBox`es which should have an effect on the presented squares. Basically, the two `ComboBox`es give the folder and the file name.

Everytime I call the `ComboBox`, I can tell that I call the paint event and the instructions used to paint the tiles are updated based upon the selection. However, the displayed squares aren't updated until I switch to another window and then turn back to the original window.

Here is how my `paintEvent` looks

```
def paintEvent(self,event):
    self.updateButtons()
    self.updateNameCombo()
    qp = QtGui.QPainter()
    qp.begin(self)
    self.paintTiles(qp)
    qp.end()
    return
```

`updateButton` is used to place the `PushButton` and `ComboBox` at the right side of the screen. `UpdateNameComobo` is used to update one of the comboBoxes and `paintTiles` is used to paint the squares on the screen.

```
  def paintTiles(self,qp):
        self.loadTileSet()
        width= self.frameSize().width()
        height = self.frameSize().height()
        self.endX = width - 120
        self.endY = width - 25
        x = self.startX
        y = self.startY
        i = self.startI
        while i < len(self.tiles):
            self.handleTile(qp,x,y,self.tiles[i])
            i += 1
            x += 60
            if x >= self.endX - 60:
                x = self.startX
                y += 60
            if y >= self.endY - 60:
                break
        return
```

`loadTileSet` is used to read the tile data from the hard drive. and `handleTile` is used to paint a single square.

```
    def handleTile(self,qp,x,y,tile):
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.blue, 1, QtCore.Qt.DotLine)
        for line in tile:
            r,g,b,a = tile[line]
            clr = QtGui.QColor(r,g,b,a)
            pen.setColor(clr)
            qp.setPen(pen)
            pX = x + line[0]
            pY = y + line[1]
            qp.drawPoint(pX,pY)
```

So, what is holding back the drawing of the tiles?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by linking the `ComboBox`es to a function that call the `update` function:

Linking,

```
self.nameCombo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.comboChanged)
```

the function,

```
self.comboChanged(self):
  self.updateComboData()
  self.update()
```

Note that when loading the gui for the first time, the `currentIndexChanged` signal is sent.